# Trying to find percentage of overlap using turf intersect returns 'found non-noded intersection between LINESTRING'

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, turf

This worked just the other day and now it's throwing an error for every call.

The original code (before adding the try/catch) is this:

```
var cbgShape = turf.polygon(shapeData.geometry.coordinates.geometry.coordinates);
var intersection = turf.intersect(isochronePolygon, cbgShape);
```

Then, it started throwing the 'non-noded intersection' error from turf.intersect, so I wrapped it in the try/catch.

```
//determine intersection between the current polygon and the isochrone polygon
var cbgShape = turf.polygon(shapeData.geometry.coordinates.geometry.coordinates);
var intersection;
try {
    intersection = turf.intersect(isochronePolygon, cbgShape);
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    intersection = null;
}

var cbgArea = turf.area(cbgShape);
var overlapArea = 0;
var overlapPercentage = 0.0;
if (intersection) {
    overlapArea = turf.area(intersection);
    overlapPercentage = (overlapArea / cbgArea) * 100;
}
```

And now, there are no intersections at all, which is of course, incorrect.  Many of the cbgShape polygons are completely within the isochronePolygon.

This all worked just fine a few days ago and the code that generates the isochronePolygon (which is from Mapbox) hasn't changed, and the code that generates each of the cbgShape polygons hasn't changed.  The data that is used for the cbgShape polygons hasn't changed (it comes from static data stored in the database).

So, where do I begin look to resolve this?  I have already tried reverting to older code, but it's still happening.  Help!

Comment: Error might be result of self intersecting polygons. Have you checked that? Turf library has also `unkinkPolygon` method for such cases.

Comment: Thank you @TomazicM...your comment put me on the path to figuring out the issue.    The Mapbox Isochrone service has a parameter called 'generalize' that when used can result in self-intersecting polygons.  From the documentation:  **Note that the generalization of contours can lead to self-intersections, as well as intersections of adjacent contours.**